# How to use static ip working internet in wp8 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I have no internet access on my WP8 emulator . I cannot open any website in the Internet Explorer within WP8 emulator. My problem exactly look like below link : https://superuser.com/questions/504189/no-internet-access-on-wp8-emulator-despite-working-connection-in-win8.I am using static ip in my windows 8 system